# How do I create a BigQuery Scheduled Query that calls a script/stored procedure with Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to modify a python script that i inherited (I am new to Python) that creates BigQuery Scheduled Queries that are located in a json file.  This script works fine until I needed to add a stored procedure to it.

The Stored Procedure doesn't have a destination table, destination dataset, or a write preference.  However, if I leave those null, blank or don't pass them I get errors telling me I need to provide a destination table and dataset.  If I pass them then BigQuery tells me I can't have a destination table for a script.  I've found a lot of documentation on simply setting this up but nothing on calling scripts.

Below are examples of what i have so far.

json

```
{
    "query_file": "./scheduled/gaps.sql",
    "schedule": "Every 15 Minutes",
    "dest_dataset": "dataset",
    "dest_table": "gaps"
},
{
        "query_file": "./scheduled/stored_procedure.sql",
        "schedule": "Every 15 Minutes",
        "dest_dataset": "",
        "dest_table": ""
    }
```

where this is called, which isp retty much the same as in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/samples/bigquerydatatransfer-create-scheduled-query#bigquerydatatransfer_create_scheduled_query-python)

```
transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer.TransferConfig(

    destination_dataset_id=schedule.dest_dataset,
    display_name=schedule.formatted_display_name(),
    data_source_id="scheduled_query",
    params={
        "query": query.replace("${project}.", f"{self._project_id}."),
        "destination_table_name_template": schedule.dest_table,
         "write_disposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        "partitioning_field": ""
    },
    schedule=schedule.schedule
)

result = self._transfer_client.create_transfer_config(
    bigquery_datatransfer.CreateTransferConfigRequest(
        parent=self._parent,
        transfer_config=transfer_config,
        service_account_name=self._service_account_name
    ),
)
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask for the following details for my proper replication of your use case? 1.) How do you use the JSON file you mentioned above on your python code? 2.) What is the content of your gaps.sql? 3.) What is the content of your stored_procedure.sql? 4.) What is the value of query that you used in this line of code --> "query" : query.replace()? Thanks!

Comment: 1). So the JSON file is parsed and the values are used in the Python above it.  So "dest_dataset" is placed in the "Schedule.dest_table variable.

2). gaps.sql just says "call SP.exe"

3). my test one simply writes some records to a table.  So it writes "apple" to a field

Comment: cont...

3). my test one simply writes some records to a table.  So it writes "apple" to a field

4). Project_id is the dataset in BQ.  So this sets up our queries to run. So they may be select * from ${project}.something.

Comment: so I lied.  It doesn't say "call ...exe" it says "
CALL `Project.schema.proc_process`();:  for #3.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled query is designed to run... queries. Stored procedure isn't a query, it's a procedure, that you can invoke from a query.

That introduction to tell you that you have 2 types of object: Query and stored procedure. You have to make an evolution in your JSON schema and add the type of object (query, function, procedure, view,...) and your code need to perform different BigQuery API calls accordingly.

But, be careful, there is a trap in that design because some object can have dependencies with others. For instance, you create a stored procedure and a query that use the stored procedure. The stored procedure must be created before the scheduled query, else it will fail.

So, the problem that you have to solve is not simple. That's why, for those kind of dependencies and configuration, IaC (infrastructure as code) tools like Terraform are very powerful to manage the dependency (explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Although that is disappointing since in BigQuery you can create a "Scheduled Query" that calls a Stored Procedure.  It allows you to not set a destination table or dataset.  However, in google's documentation they don't reference that and when I try to adjust it, the code doesn't work.  Seems like it should be possible.